# "Forced" or "Was forced"

Tags: tense, sentence-choice

I am wondering which option is the correct one in my made-up scenario below and why?

> **Tom:** I really didn't want to take part in this ceremony; I just came because my wife asked me! Everybody knows that I don't like your husband Anna.

Anna gets annoyed and says sarcastically:

> **Anna:** Nobody ............. to come. You didn't have to come where you don't like.

1. forced you
2. was forcing you

Comment: I would go with either "asked you to come" or "forced you to come". "Nobody was forcing you to come" sounds unnatural to me and is quite possibly incorrect.

Comment: The "was forcing" is ok, it suggests that Tom chose to go even though other people told (or suggested to) him not to go.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Can you give me an example of when "Nobody was forcing you to come" is more appropriate than "Nobody forced you to come"? I can't think of a context like that. "Nobody *is* forcing you to *go*" is correct because it shows the continuous present. But I really can't think of a context where "nobody forced you to come" is not a better choice than "nobody was forcing you to come".

Comment: @AIQ, both phrases seem good to me, both are ways of referring to passed events. I am not sure that either is better than the other. Perhaps the choice is based on usage in different parts of the UK preferring different wording.

Comment: They are both grammatical. Which to use is entirely a matter of opinion.

Comment: Do they both make the same sense in this context @Jason Bassford?

Comment: @A-friend Yes, they both make sense.